# Compatibility of system of $\ell$-adic representations associated to Voevodsky motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, motives

Let $M$ be an object of Voevodsky's category $DM_{gm}(K,\mathbb{Q})$ for a number field $K$. For each prime number $\ell$, there is an $\ell$-adic realization $M_{\ell}$ in the bounded derived category of continuous $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-linear representations of $G_K$ (see e.g. Huber's book on realizations of motives). For $M=M(X)$ the motive of a smooth variety, we know that the system $\{H^i(M_{\ell})\}_{\ell}$ is weakly compatible in the sense that for almost all $\ell$, the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius is independent of $\ell$.

Is $\{H^i(M_{\ell})\}_{\ell}$ weakly compatible for arbitrary $M$? For a complex $0 \to X_m \to \cdots \to X_n \to 0$ of varieties, the trace of the $q$-power Frobenius at a prime of good reduction would give the alternating sum $\sum_{i=m}^n (-1)^i \#X_i(\mathbb{F}_q)$. It would then seem that one could deal with the Karoubian envelope using an argument like in https://mathoverflow.net/a/212374/1355. But it's not entirely obvious to me what to do about the fact that our idempotents that form the Karoubian envelope are homotopy classes of maps of complexes of varieties (already with some localization). I'm also a little unsure about how to deal with different degrees of cohomology, but maybe Bondarko's weight filtration deals with that?

Comment: The known result is for a smooth *projective* variety. Even for smooth quasi-projective varieties it is as hard as the general case of independence of $\ell$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00119). Since smooth quasi-projective varieties give elements of $DM_{gm}(K, \mathbb Q)$ I think this shows your question is as hard as the general case also.

Comment: @WillSawin there is a slight difference between the setting of this question and my paper: David is asking about motives over a number field. So at least we know that the Betti numbers are independent of $\ell$ (although studying the Frobenius action via reduction modulo $p$ is not a thing, as you cannot apply the smooth and proper base change theorems). Another difference is that this question asks about independence for *almost* all $\ell$. I have discussed that variant with some people, but did not pursue it as ultrafilter methods are ineffective: you'll never know which $\ell$ to toss out.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Ah, sorry for misrepresenting.

Comment: @WillSawin Are you sure we don't know it for an arbitrary smooth variety? There's a weight filtration coming from the geometry of the boundary divisor, and all the graded pieces come from* cohomology of the same smooth proper varieties. And since characteristic polynomial is additive in exact sequences, we get the comparison.

*They might be pieces of cohomology of boundary divisors, but they are cut out by all the same cycles for all $\ell$.

Comment: Well, I was getting characteristic $p$ and characteristic $0$ confused, but I do still think we don't know it for smooth varieties in characteristic $0$. Moreover, your argument seems dubious to me - in part because it's not clear where the characteristic $0$ assumption is used. The graded pieces in question arise from some spectral sequence, so they can be expressed as the kernel of some map modulo the image of some other map. Those maps are probably induced by cycles but then how do we find idempotent cycles to cut out the subquotient as a summand?

Comment: Are you willing to assume any open conjectures to deduce the result you want? I don't think that you can prove the statement you want unconditionally already in the case of   a single smooth variety or of (the cone of) an embedding of smooth projective varieties.